# Using Fieldcalculator with dynamic values

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, attribute-table

I want to use the `field calculator` to calculate something. I have two ways how to do this. One works as expected, the other does not

This one does not work

```
("col1" - maximum("col1"))/ (maximum("col1") / minimum("col1"))
```

It returns 0. However, when I hardcode the `maximum` and `minimum` values the functions `maximum("col1")` and `minimum("col1")` return, I get the the result as expected

```
("col1" - 10)/ (10 / 3)
```

Why is that?

Comment: because the first one requires 2 passes through the data

Comment: it works for me! QGIS 3.22

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To speed up the calculations it is better to create variables, one for the maximun and the other for the minimum, so they are calculated only once:

```
with_variable('max', maximum(fid),
      with_variable('min', minimum(fid),
               (fid - @max)/(@max / @min)))
```

[image]